# How can I make use of TrackingId in Service Bus Exceptions?

Tags: c#, azure, azureservicebus, servicebus, azure-servicebus-topics

While using Service Bus for Windows Server,  all exceptions that I've contain **TrackingId**. How can i make use of it ?

Exception Sample:

> [Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.NoMatchingSubscriptionException] = {"There is no matching subscription found for the message with MessageId 'a4f83bca6f7e49f691ac9953ac121689'..**TrackingId**:048fcfab-ed16-4453-a897-903f3777dc87_GAmrVM-VS_BAmrVM-VS,TimeStamp:8/2/2015 1:36:35 PM"}

Note : I dive deep in [ SBMessageContainer0X ] Db without any results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tracking ID is only for if you need to call customer support - normally for something more complex than this. You can't do anything more with the tracking id yourself. That error string effectively ends before "TrackingId...".

Now if you had some sort of error you didn't understand - perhaps like this - and you provide that to Azure support they will use that tracking ID to start investigating.